# C, pointer, string

Tags: c, pointers

```
main()
{
  char *x="girl";
  int n,i;
   n=strlen(x);
  *x=x[n];
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
   printf("%s \n",x);
    x++;
  }
}
```

What is the output?
Please explain the output.......................
o/p is :

```
irl
rl
l
```

Comment: Result = UB = Undefined Behavio(u)r

Comment: Change `char*x` to `char x[]` to avoid undefined behaviour.

Comment: @missingno: there are more UB issues with the code; the modifying a string literal is not alone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the program as written has undefined behaviour.

If you make a small alteration:

```
char x[] = "girl";
```

then I believe it is legal, and possible to explain. (EDIT: Actually there are still problems with it. It's `int main()`, and you should `return 0;` at the end. You also need to `#include <string.h>` because you are using `strlen`, and `#include <stdio.h>` because you are using `printf`.)

The line

```
*x = x[n];
```

sets `x[0]` (i.e. `*x`) to `x[4]` (which happens to be the string terminator `'\0'`). Thus the first string to be printed is the empty string, because the very first character is the string terminator.

We then loop through the string, one character at a time, printing the substrings:

```
irl
rl
l
```

Answer (score 4):

The output is undefined behaviour. You modified a string literal.

Comment: ... and called a variadic function without a prototype in scope; and didn't return a value from `main` (the code is not C99 (which would accept a main without a return) because C99 forbids implicit `int`).

Comment: @Adi: You only changed the word in the string. That doesn't change the UB.

Answer (score 1):

While the result is undefined behavior, as DeadMG said, let's assume you declared x as `char x[] = "girl"`.

You assign 4 to `n` (since the length of the word "girl" is 4), and you assign the value in `x[4]` to `*x` (which is `x[0]`), but this value is '\0' (null terminator)

Now you loop and print the word from x to the next null terminator, but the first time, the first char is the null terminator, so you get nothing. after that you print the word from incrementing index.

```
g   i    r   l   \0

*x = x[4]:

\0   i    r    l   \0
^    ^    ^    ^
it1  it2  it3  it4      // << Where does x points to in each iteration of the for loop
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is distictly suspect.  `*x=x[n]` attempts to overwrite the literal "girl", and the effect will vary between platforms and compilers.  More correctly it should be declared as:

```
const char *x = "girl";
```

and then it will not (should not) compile.

Comment: More correctly he should be making it safe to modify the string, not forcing his entire program to break by making the original non-mutability of the string compiler-checked.

Comment: Huh? How is it more correct to write code which will not compile?

Comment: @Simon: it's "more correct" in the sense that it won't *allow* him to modify a string literal; IOW, the compiler will catch those kinds of errors for him.